# concatenate two lists of string and attach index in r

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

Here is my sample:

```
stringa = c("a","b","c")
stringb = c("high","low","average")
index = c(1,2,3)

data <- data.frame(stringa,stringb,index)
```

I would like to concatenate stringa and stringb, and attach the corresponding index in another column. For example, the first row of the result should be "a high" with index "1".

Now I have used this function to concatenate the two strings:

```
c(outer(a, b, paste))
```

Comment: What happened? Was it not as expected?

Answer (score 1):

For "a high", "b low", "c average" you can do:

```
stringa = c("a","b","c")
stringb = c("high","low","average")
index = c(1,2,3)
data.frame(concatenated = paste(stringa, stringb),index)
  concatenated
1    a high
2    b low
3    c average
```

For the full permutations of stringa and stringb:

```
stringa = c("a","b","c")
stringb = c("high","low","average")
data.frame(concatenated = c(outer(stringa, stringb, paste) ) )
    concatenated
1       a high
2       b high
3       c high
...
9    c average
```

If you want to explicitly add the row index:

```
df = data.frame(concatenated = c(outer(stringa, stringb, paste) ) )
df$index = rownames(df)
df 
  concatenated index
1       a high     1
2       b high     2
3       c high     3
...
9    c average     9
```

Comment: I also need to concatenate "a" with "low" and "average"